# ContextMenu for blank space of an Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, space, android-contextmenu

Is there a way I can get a context menu pop up when a user long presses on the blank space of a listview? I know that this can be done by setting wrap_content to the layout_height parameter of the listview. In fact I have been doing that successfully for a while. However, sometimes this wrap_content behaves very strangely and though there is enough space on the screen the listview restricts itself to a % of the screen and items scroll within that space. To avoid that problem I have moved to the path of setting the height as 0dp and weight as 1. However, that has disturbed the functionality I had in terms of long pressing the empty area of a list to add a new item to the list. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have looked at multiple similar questions on SO throughout the day today but couldn't find any conclusive and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListView#addHeaderView() or ListView#addFooterView() to add extra view at the top or bottom of ListView, which you can make it looks like blank space.
Also I suggest you use match_parent to the layout_height attribute of ListView.

Comment: Lets say I have 3 items in the list view, how will the footer occupy rest of the space on the screen dynamically and automatically?

Comment: @Sriman In this case footer view is like a 4th item (it's always placed at the end of listview).

Comment: you are right. but how can i make the footer automatically occupy the remaining space on the screen? Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Sriman There are several cases. 1. there are only a few items thus the screen remains a lot space; 2. there are so many items that they couldn't be filled in a screen, you have to scroll it; 3. there are several items, screen only have little space. I wonder what do you exactly want in these situation, could you provide more detail?

Comment: In cases 1 and 3 I want the footer to occupy whatever remaining space on the screen not occupied by the listview. In case 2, I dont want to the footer at all..

Comment: @Sriman If in case 2 you dont want the footer then does it mean user is unable to long press to add new item in case 2? It is kind of inconsistent compared to case 1&3. What if the remain space is only 10dp while the item is 30dp? The ListView still will scroll. If you don't wanna add new item once items can occupy the whole screen, then I think using LinearLayout rather than ListView might give you more customization. Sorry that I didnt come up with any suitable solution. :p

Comment: I already have the context menu defined for the listview. That has a bunch of options like editing an item, deleting an item apart from adding new item. So when there are enough items to fill the screen, I dont need the footer.